# Does downvoting a 1-rep user's question or answer have any further effect on the OP's account?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes

We all know (I suppose), that a user's rep can't fall below 1.

I'm wondering though, if more (not primarily indicated) downvotes on the user's posts might have any further side effects, to how this account is handled by the SE engine.

Comment: reputation-wise, no, but i'm positive it will affect the rate-limiting of asking questions or answering. (the actual affects likely won't be confirmed or denied by se staff to prevent gaming of the system)

Comment: @Louis **Nope!** I disagree, that doesn't clearly answer my question!

Comment: How do you downvote a user? I've only seen voting on questions, answers, etc. never people.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Fixed that wording ...

Comment: I don't know how the SE devs handle reputation underflow, maybe they trigger undefined behavior on the client side so dragons come out from these users' noses. Which would be awesome, by the way.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No, I don't believe that _nasal demons_ would apply here. It's certainly not raising UB of the SE engine. I think, the downvotes still count, unless the OP edits such a question/answer and its upvoted in turn. As far I've noticed, even deleting a question or answer doesn't leverage the OP from being question/answer banned.

Comment: What is a "not primarily indicated" vote in this context?

Comment: @πάντα, ah, my would-be humorous point about *on the client side* apparently fell flat ;) But I would be interested in the basis you have for *I think, the downvotes still count, unless the OP edits such a question/answer and its upvoted in turn*.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan _"primarily indicated"_ I meant _'Not showing the rep below 1'_.

Comment: It can't reduce reputation, but enough highly downvoted questions can result in the user being suspended/banned from asking questions, and the same negative impact is possible on heavily downvoted answers. So yes, it can have a further result (suspension/banning) on the user's account.